# Is there a fast way to remove malloc/free/memalign/realloc hooks in glibc?

Tags: c, glibc

I've tried to patch the libc i'm using to never call malloc hook. But this hook is actually initialized with a pointer to this function:

```c
malloc_hook_ini (size_t sz, const void *caller)
{
      __malloc_hook = NULL;
      ptmalloc_init ();
      return __libc_malloc (sz);
}
```

I think this function is responsible for critical initializations in malloc, so it needs to be called at least once. For instance since the free hook is not initialized with a critical function, i can just nop the call instruction

Comment: Does the line `__malloc_hook = NULL;` not ensure that this function is not called again — so it is only called on the first call to `malloc()`?

Comment: When malloc is called it checks if malloc_hook is set, as if it is then i calls it. An attacker might change the malloc_hook content to a function at choice.
Nevertheless, i changed the libc source and compile it myself, problem solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DJ Delorie [posted a patch](https://sourceware.org/ml/libc-alpha/2018-04/msg00131.html) which removes the hooks. It requires some porting to the current tree, though.

Alternatively, you could [interpose a different malloc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Replacing-malloc.html) which does not have such hooks. If you do this, glibc will use the interposed malloc, so the hooks are never called, either.